# IBeacon. Custom filter regions

Tags: ibeacon, region, beacon, altbeacon

Good day. Sorry my English is bad. Whether prompt there is an opportunity to define region of bicons not on UUID and on it is one part. For example, we have 2 regions:

1 -  UUID =  57547265-7261-772e-636f-6c0054000000

2- there is only the full part (most likely this is the fourth last group) - 
   6c001137e000

**Can I just specify in my method a filter only for the last group of UUID?**

For example:

```
List<string> listUuids =new List<string>()
             { "57547265-7261-772e-636f-6c0054000000" , "6c001137e000" };

    for (int i = 0; i <listUuids.Count; i ++)
      {
      var uuid = Identifier.Parse (listUuids [i]);
      var region = new Region ("R" + i, uuid, null, null);
      beaconManager.StartRangingBeaconsInRegion (region);
      }
```

I would really appreciate any answers!
Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom beacon parser.  Like this:

`BeaconManager.GetBeaconParsers().clear();
BeaconMannager.GetBeaconParsers().add(new Beacon parser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:14-19,i:4-13,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
var region = new Region("partial UUID region",  Identifier.parse("0x6c001137e000"), null, null)`

The above custom parser defines *four* identifiers for a iBeacon packet.  The first identifier is the last 6 bytes of the UUID.  The second identifier is the first 10 bytes of the UUID.  The third and fourth identifiers are the major and minor, respectively.

Using the region defined above will match any beacon matching the specified last 6 bytes of the UUID.

Comment: Thank's! I will try